# How long and how much can I benefit from praying?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

When you pray on a shrine you get a temporary buff, how long does this buff last?

Also, how many of this buffs can I have simultaneously?

Comment: I've had at least 2 up simultaneously. Haven't timed them to see how long though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had over 25 buffs on myself, so if there is a limit, it's pretty darn high.

To test this out, I bought a bunch of buff potions and drank them all. Twenty in total. Then I touched the 5 shrines that are right next to each other in Ysa. Only 15 buffs displayed on the screen at once, so at first maybe I thought there was a cap of 15.

[image]

However, when I went to the Status->Effects screen, it listed all 25 buffs as active. My guess is that the 15 that displayed on the screen were all it had room for.

[image]

Potion buffs seem to have variable durations depending on the potion type. I am not prepared to make a list of every single potion type and their individual durations, but of the 20 I tested, all seemed to fall into two categories... **30 seconds** or **60 seconds**. I didn't detect any sort of pattern about why some lasted 30 seconds and other lasted 60.

> **All shrine buffs appear to have a duration of 5 minutes.**
>
> **Potion buffs seem to be either 30 seconds or 60 seconds.**

Comment: It's worth noting that the "Minor Phasewalk" potion lasts much less than 30 seconds. I didn't time it, but it seemed to be in the 10-15 second range.